# Adding an element to a matrix array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var teams = new Array();
var teamsv2 = new Array();

var num_team = 18;

for (var x = 0; x < num_team; x++) {
  teams[x] = x + 1;
}

for (let tb = 0; tb < teams.length; tb++) {
    teamsv2[[tb][0]] = teams[tb];
}
```

I created a array called teams2. For example I wanna to add some data this teams2 array.

like this;

```
teamsv2[[2][0]].push("stackoverflow");
```

```
teamsv2[[0][1]],
teamsv2[[1][1]]
```

I want to fill the second parts of the first index of the array.
How can I do that?

Comment: You seem to be using an extra pair of braces everywhere.  It's generally `obj [x] [y]`.  Note that `obj [ [x] [y] ]` is quite different, and probably not what you mean.

Comment: when I write  console.log(teamsv2[1][1])  I want to see like this; 8

Comment: You haven't made a 2d array so you can't access a nested index.

Comment: @pilchard How can I create 2d array

Comment: last element  of teamsv2 array like this  = [...,[17][0],[17][1],[17][2],[17][3],[17][4],[17][5] ,[17][6], [17][7]]  but I want to add data later in array

Comment: I want to add name in first index of array and other information in other indexes @NinaScholz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a 2-dimensional array, each element of the array should be an array of its own. Right now, you are creating 2 flat arrays.

`[[tb][0]]` will create a new array of length 1 with the value of `tb`, access the 0th index, which is just the value of `tb`. So it's a lot of syntax, but `[[tb][0]]` is the same as `[tb]` which is why you are only getting 1-dimensional arrays.

If you "want to fill the second parts of the first index of the array"...

```
// replace this
teamsv2[[tb][0]] = teams[tb];

// with this
teamsv2[tb] = [ teams[tb] ];
```

And now you can access the new array like so:

```
console.log(teamsv2[0][0]); // returns team name

teamsv2[0].push("some info");

console.log(teamsv2[0][1]); // returns "some info"

console.table(teamsv2); // returns something like...
//  (index)   0            1             2
//  0         'Knights'    'some info'
//  1         'Marlins'    'foo'         'example'
//  2         'Volcanoes'  'bar'         'more'
```

Comment: thank you for the solution!  teamsv2[0][2] or teamsv2[0][4] if i want to send data how can i do that

Comment: Could you explain what data you want to send and how it relates to the indices you listed?